# How do I export data in accordance to HAL spec?

Tags: spring-data, hateoas, spring-hateoas

According to [this](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) specification, applications exposing data in hal+json format should provide embedded links in the _links json field. However, if I declare my REST Repository in spring-data 1.5.9 like this:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "storage-node", excerptProjection = IBrief.class)
public interface IStorageNodeRepository extends JpaRepository<StorageNode, Long> {
  @Query("FROM StorageNode sn WHERE sn.parent is null order by sn.uploadTs ASC")
  List<StorageNode> findAllRootNodes();
}
```

I get the following json:

```
{
  "nodeType" : "Image",
  "text" : "100.jpeg",
  "uploadTs" : "2018-01-11T23:48:25.724Z",
   /* ... Irrelevant ... */
  "links" : [ {
    "rel" : "self",
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/emerald/api/hal/storage-node/31"
  }
  /* ... Irrelevant ... */
}
```

As we can see, it exports links in "links" field, without the leading underscore. Is there additional configuration required to make it export data in accordance to HAL spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After giving it some thought, I've discovered this fragment.

```
  @Bean
  public RepositoryRestConfigurer repositoryRestConfigurer() {
    return new RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.setBasePath("/api/hal");
        config.setDefaultMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
      }
    };
  }
```

Removing default media type did the job.
I don't remember exactly under which circumstances I've added this. Maybe I had to explicitly say `;charset=utf8` in each response to deal with russian strings.

Comment: I think it should still work with russian characters without the default media type. The response has the header:Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8

I've updated the test application at github.com/dwdking/hal-test to include an entry with some russian characters and it seems to display correctly

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Spring HATEOAS does HAL out of the box. You can enabled it by adding the following to your configuration:

```
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)
```

See similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431087/returned-json-unexpected-has-links-spelled-as-links-and-structure-differen) and the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#configuration.at-enable)

If you are using spring boot the relevant configuration in the application.properties would be (although this I believe is defaulted to true in at-least 1.5.9 of boot):

```
spring.hateoas.use-hal-as-default-json-media-type: true
```

Comment: What version of Spring HATEOAS are you using and where is the annotation?

Comment: Version is in the post. annotation is applied to @Configuration bean

Comment: The link to question you provided describes writing custom HATEOAS enabled REST services. I'm not writing my own service here (they return _links as expected, when result is wrapped in Resource<>, BTW), the problem is with built-in controller.

Comment: It has something to do with your configuration. I'm not seeing a similar issue in this sample project here: https://github.com/dwdking/hal-test

Can you post source somewhere or create an issue in a minimal example?

Comment: config.setDefaultMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);